# Mapping a string using a map

Tags: clojure

```clj
(def conversions {"G" "C"
                  "C" "G"
                  "T" "A"
                  "A" "U"})

(defn to-rna [dna]
  (map conversions dna)
)

(conversions "G") ;; Gives "C"

(to-rna "GC")     ;; Gives (nil nil)
```

I'm attempting to do an exercise where I convert letters. I have *a* working solution, but I don't like it. I feel like the above ought to work, but evidently I'm wrong, because it doesn't.

Could someone explain to me why this is, and how I might properly achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

When mapping over a string, it will treat the string as a sequence of characters. So, your code ends up looking for a \G and a \C entry in the map, which both return nil.

Answer (score 5):

As dpassen says, you need to put a  `java.lang.Character` in the map, not a length-1 string.  Try this:

```
(def conversions { \G  \C
                   \C  \G
                   \T  \A
                   \A  \U })
```

Comment: I guess and an `(apply str (map conversions dnd)) `

Answer (score 4):

I'm just starting learning Clojure myself so please take this answer with caution.

In addition to what's been already suggested, I would put the conversions map into a `let` form to keep your function "isolated". (As is, your function relies on a `conversions` being defined outside of its scope).

I also read (can't remember where exactly) that a common naming convention when writing functions that "convert" X to Y should be named as follow: `x->y`.

Finally I'd use a threading macro for improved readability.

```clj
(defn dna->rna [dna]
  (let [conversions {\G \C
                     \C \G
                     \T \A
                     \A \U}]
    (->> dna
         (map conversions)
         (string/join ""))))

(dna->rna "GC")
;; "CG"
```

Answer (score 3):

FYI, Clojure has clojure.string/escape and clojure.string/replace that you might want to look at.  escape is probably most similar to what you are doing.